# How to create .so lib file for NDK project?

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, android-ndk

I've been working on NDK project for a while now and I've only used samples to build my project and they all had lib folder with generated files.

I've tried creating my project from scratch and it failed with first run saying that library is not found. I then realised I'm missing lib folder and that's why app can't find my .cpp library.

Now I can't find an answer to how to make Eclipse auto generate .so library to be used as my native library in NDK project.

Is this usually generate in Eclipse? Do I need to use GCC in terminal to generate them? Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add android ndk tools to a location where your android sdk is present.

Now in your eclipse project, create a jni folder with all your .c and .h files and also your Android.mk file.

Now in your eclipse, goto Run -> External Tools -> External Tools Configuration.
For location, press "Browse File System" and choose the "ndk-build" location(which you have put in android sdk folder)
For Working Directory, press "Browse Workspace" and choose your eclipse project and your jni folder. For example like this - ${workspace_loc:/yourproject/jni}

Press Apply and then press Run. You have your .so in libs folder of your eclipse project.